# Opencv python incorrect blocksize

Tags: python, opencv

```
def adaptive_gaussian_thresholding(self, filename):
    im = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
    filtered_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(im, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 3, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 3, 0)
    cv2.imwrite(filename, filtered_image)
```

> ```
> filtered_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(im, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 3, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 3, 0)
> error: /root/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:1287: error: (-215) blockSize % 2 == 1 && blockSize > 1 in function adaptiveThreshold
> ```

The blocksize or tile size is the number of pixels^2 to be used for the kernel that is passed to the procedure. It needs to be an odd number. I am unsure if this is a bug or something else is wrong?

[Official documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cv2.adaptiveThreshold)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `adaptiveThreshold` with an extra argument. You have incorrectly placed a `3` in between the `adaptiveMethod` and `thresholdType` arguments. In your invocation, the `cv2.THRESH_BINARY` flag is in the position expected for the `blockSize` value. Incidentally, `cv2.THRESH_BINARY` evaluates to zero, hence the error you see. The correct way to call your function is:

```
filtered_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(im, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 3, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think what confused me was you seem to be missing the 'dst' or destination src for the file. You have specified an input, but not an output.

Comment: @user5275692 In the Python bindings, the output of the algorithm is almost always returned from the function, so `filtered_image` is the output. The `dst`parameter is purely optional and a holdover from the C++ API.

Answer (score 1):

If you do call the `help()` for that function in python, the call needs to respect the following form:

```
Help on built-in function adaptiveThreshold in module cv2:

adaptiveThreshold(...)
    adaptiveThreshold(src, maxValue, adaptiveMethod, thresholdType, blockSize, C[, dst])
```

The value `3` between the `adaptiveMethod` and `thresholdType` in your call should be omitted.

And `C` is subtracted from the mean or weighted mean calculated maybe insert a value `e.g. 2`.

example call:
`mycall= cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
  cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)`